# Active X slow to load first time

Tags: activex

I have an Active X control, which when first called or loaded in my asp.net application, is really slow to load. However, after the first load, it is really quick!!

My question is this, "How do I make my Active X control, when first called, load much faster? Is there away to preload the active x to the page so when it is used or called, it doesn't take so long to load?"

I have checked to see whether my active x is being called correctly by my javascript code, and it does. All my Active X does is to make a call to Outlook and to set some user properties. Not much.

Please help, but it has been doing my head in for days.

Comment: Are you running the AX control in the HTML running on the client computer? If so, what technology did you use to write your ActiveX control? If it's managed code (and not C/C++/Delphi) then you should rewrite in Native Code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the .Net Framework 1.1, 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 You have a few options. Upgrade to the 4.0 Framework, preferably with IIS 7 which has the ability to ping your site and deep it alive. If you are not able to upgrade you could also use a ping utility to keep your site "alive". Basically what this does is it hits your site every few minutes so that you do not encounter the 20 min. default timeout period of you application domain. When you application domain times out it is reloaded on the next request, hence the slowness you are experiencing.

http://www.spikesolutions.net/ViewSolution.aspx?ID=c2b7edc0-5de1-4064-a432-05f6eded3b82

Comment: I suspect he's likely talking about an ActiveX control that's running on the user's client computer.

Comment: Yes the Active X is using Framework 3.5 and needs to use this because it is linking to an Outlook Client - Outlook 2003, and we can't upgrade from this. The problem that we have is that the Active X is only activated when the uses comes to use it through clicking a button.